# Python - create dictionary with multiple keys and where value is also dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
test={"11.67":1,"12.67":2}
```

My desired output is the following:

```
{'11.67': {'value': '11'}, '12.67': {'value': '12}}
```

Value in second dictionary is the first index when doing the split on the key.

I wrote this:

```
test={"11.67":1,"12.67":2}
indexes=test.keys()
final_dict={}
temp_dict={}
for index in indexes:
    b=index.split('.')[0]
    temp_dict['value']=b;
    final_dict.update({index:temp_dict})
print (final_dict)
```

But result is wrong:

```
{'11.67': {'value': '12'}, '12.67': {'value': '12'}}
```

Not sure what is going wrong.
Thanks

And one more ***UPDATE:***
I must use **indexes**  which is dict_keys.
I must start from that part of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could just do this:

```
test = {"11.67": 1, "12.67": 2}
res = {key: {"value": str(int(float(key)))} for key in test}
# {'11.67': {'value': '11'}, '12.67': {'value': '12'}}
```

where i first convert the strings to `float`s, then discard the fractional part by using `int` and convert back to `str` again.

what goes wrong in your code is nicely explained in [Carsten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107642/4954037).

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I must use indexes , because I am starting the code from that part
And one more ***UPDATE:***
I must use **indexes**  which is dict_keys.
I must start from that part of the code.

Comment: then it would just be `for key in indexes`. (instead of `for key in test`).

Answer (score 4):

Your error lies in declaring the `temp_dict` outside the loop. This works:

```
test={"11.67":1,"12.67":2}
indexes=test.keys()
final_dict={}
for index in indexes:
    temp_dict={}
    b=index.split('.')[0]
    temp_dict['value']=b;
    final_dict.update({index:temp_dict})
print (final_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are always referring to the same object `temp_dict`, hence any changes to it will be reflected in all of its instance.

I suggest using a dict comprehension to tackle your problem, which will reduce dictionary creation to just one line:

```
final_dict = {idx: {'value': idx.split('.')[0]} for idx in test.keys()}
```

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
>>> {i:{'value': "%d"%eval(i)} for i in {"11.67":1,"12.67":2}}
{'11.67': {'value': '11'}, '12.67': {'value': '12'}}
>>>
```

`{}` -> dictionary comprehension and old string `"%s"` formating

Answer (score 1):

After importing temp_dict into the final_dict, clear the temp_dict.
GOOD_LUCK

```
test={"11.67":1, "12.67":2, "15.66":3}
indexes = test.keys()
final_dict = {}
temp_dict = {}
for index in indexes:
    b = index.split('.')[0]
    temp_dict['value'] = b
    final_dict[index] = temp_dict
    temp_dict = {}
print(final_dict)
```